# Spreading user reported variables to multiple columns

Tags: r

I am trying to seperate a couple of user filled variables into multiple columns. I have tried to use the spread function, but I am running into some problems. For example, the database looks like this:

```
SubjID         Input1        Input2
1              Banana        NA
2              Apple         NA
3              NA            Banana
4              Apple         Banana
```

And I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
SubjID         Input1        Input2    Banana   Apple
1              Banana        NA        Banana   NA
2              Apple         NA        NA       Apple
3              NA            Banana    Banana   Na
4              Apple         Banana    Banana   Apple
```

I can use the spread function in tidyr to separate input 1, but the problem comes with input 2. I am able to spread it, but I cant put the values into the previously created Banana column, it will instead create two banana columns, which I cannot figure out how to merge correctly. Is there any way to have it sort into the columns correctly? I am new to R and am having a lot of trouble with this aspect of the database. There are too many options for me to discretely state banana and apple and I am really unsure of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to `gather` first before doing the `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  gather(key, val, -SubjID, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(key1 = val) %>% 
  select(-key) %>% spread(key1, val) %>%
  left_join(df1, ., by = 'SubjID')
#  SubjID Input1 Input2 Apple Banana
#1      1 Banana   <NA>  <NA> Banana
#2      2  Apple   <NA> Apple   <NA>
#3      3   <NA> Banana  <NA> Banana
#4      4  Apple Banana Apple Banana
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SubjID = 1:4, Input1 = c("Banana", "Apple", NA, 
"Apple"), Input2 = c(NA, NA, "Banana", "Banana")), .Names = c("SubjID", 
 "Input1", "Input2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Assuming that your data.frame is called `dat`:

```
dat$Banana <- ifelse(dat$Input1 == "Banana" | dat$Input2 == "Banana", "Banana", NA)
dat$Apple <- ifelse(dat$Input1 == "Apple" | dat$Input2 == "Apple", "Apple", NA)
```

For example, the first line checks row-by-row if either `df$Input1` or `df$Input2` is "Banana"; if so, it puts `"Banana"` in the `Banana` column, else it puts `NA`.